# Calling a php file everytime when i click the button in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex

The problem i am facing right now is a filename.php generates filename.xml.... and this filename.xml is called in my Flex Tree.

Now everytime i update my DB, the values are not getting reflected into filename.xml unless i call the filename.php

Now how would i call filename.php from flex which will make the update of xml...

I have tried HTTPService and its not working.

Comment: HTTPService is the way to go. Please post the code fragments of both your php and flex HTTPService so that we can see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Mapping PHP and Flex Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032283/mapping-php-and-flex-objects) you said

> I am using ZendAMF for remoting.

Why not sending the xml data (maybe but not necessarily as xml document) the same way, i.e. via AMF/[ZendAMF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html) ?